# ZeroMQ: Can I use a ROUTER and a DEALER as server / client, instead of using them as proxies?

Tags: zeromq

I have a server/client application, which uses a **`REQ/REP`** formal pattern and I know this is synchronous.

Can I completely replace **`zmq.REQ`** / **`zmq.REP`** by `zmq.ROUTER` and `zmq.DEALER` ?

Or do these have to be used only as intermediate proxies?

Answer (score 1):

### ZeroMQ is a box with a few smart and powerful building blocks

However, only the Architect and the Designer decide how well or how poor these get harnessed in your distributed applications' architecture.

So, a synchronicity or asynchronicity is **not** an inherent feature of some particular ZeroMQ Scaleable Formal Communication Pattern's access-node, but depends on real deployment, within some larger context of use.

---

### Yes, **`ROUTER`** can talk to **`DEALER`**, but ...

as one may read in details in [ZeroMQ **API-specification tables**](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket), so called compatible socket-archetypes are listed for each named socket type, however anyone can grasp much stronger powers from ZeroMQ if trying to start using the ZeroMQ way of thinking by spending more time on the ZeroMQ concept and their set of Zero-maxims -- Zero-copy + (almost) Zero-latency + Zero-warranty + (almost) Zero-scaling degradation etc.

---

### The best next step:

IMHO if you are serious about professional messaging, get the great book and source both the elementary setups knowledge, a bit more complex multi-socket messaging layer designs with soft signaling and also the further thoughts about the great powers of concurrent, heterogeneous, distributed processing to advance your learning curve.

Pieter Hintjens' book "**Code Connected, Volume 1**" ( available in PDF ) is more than a recommended source for your issue.

There **you will get grounds** for your further use of ZeroMQ.

ZeroMQ is a great tool, not just for the messaging layer itself. Worth time and efforts.

[image: multi-socket messaging layer with soft signalling]

Comment: Hi there. May I again ask you again to tone down your edit remarks? Edits to your material are not violations, they are merely improvements, and I do them with the best of intentions. I accept they are sometimes subjective. Nevertheless, we don't want to get everyone into the habit of adding links to long lists of their own material elsewhere on the site - that information is readily available in profiles already. If you have a _specific_ relevant question to point to, by all means do link to that.

Comment: **Q1:** Do you ever **respect O/P and her/his level of domain-expertise, when deleting/flattening the already provided answers**, where someone else has sponsored the tailor-made Content creation with an amount of knowledge & altruistic efforts a Just-Deleter has never paired to match? **Q2:** In case A1 would at least somehow reflect the fact a user with a non-professional-level domain expertise would appreciate much more a way different Level-of-Detail in the Answer than an industry domain veteran, **why do you Delete & Flatten the content, right AVOIDING the O/P to follow a path to learn?**

Comment: @user3666197 - halfer's edits seem perfectly reasonable to me, as they make your answer easier to read. There's no real need to advertise your other answers across an entire topic at the end.

Comment: With all due respect, this did not reflect neither Q1 nor Q2. If StackOverflow accumulated content were intended for some automated-parsing/processing (as already observed, as the bots grow in re-using it), the presented objections would make sense, but only for bot-design / bot-re-processing concerns, but **not for the sake of the Original Question author - so who is the Supreme Customer of MY Service?** The bots?No,never. The re-publisher(s)?No,never. **The Question AUTHOR.** If a Community punishes for serving The Supreme Customer, only in that case the Just-Deleters'll will rule Answerers.

Comment: @user3666197: we had a [chat conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143989/room-for-halfer-and-user3666197), archived at the link. Feel free to ping me in that room, or create a new one, if you want to discuss related themes.